# Thunderbird and other apps in Maverics' notice panel

Tags: macos

Is there a way to tell which app is using my notices panel from Maverics (opened by fingers slide from right side to left)?

I am particularly intrested in displaying Thunderbird's new message indicators there, but it boils down to actually setting notices for anything I want there.

Any manual or sources would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences > Notifications.

All apps which have the ability to display notifications will be listed here.

If it is not listed here, then it won't work with the notifications sidebar.